# Implementing mmap in file_operations - mapping array of pages to virtual space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, driver

Let's say the memory I want to give user access to memory that is fragmented into several pages. I have two arrays of the same size: one for logical addresses and one dma_ptrs. I would like to map these consecutive fragments into one contiguous virtual address for the user so he can use it.

I really can't understand the specification of remap_pfn_range which is probably what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-2

Page array contains page frame numbers -  simply the physical address right-shifted by PAGE_SHIFT bits.

```
for(i = vm_pgoff; i < no; i++){
    remap_pfn_range(vma, virt_addr + (i - vm_pgoff) * PAGE_SIZE, page[i], PAGE_SIZE, prot);
}
```

Comment: Is this code working? It's okay to answer your own question, but make it a *good answer*; include an explanation of what the function does and what your calling code does, copy the prototype here, and link to any reference material.

Comment: Well, then it probably shouldn't be an answer... You should probably [edit your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37471297/edit) to include this code attempt.